# Trying to catch an Exception using FileDialog

Tags: java, filedialog

i am new to Java and i created a small table inside a GUI from which i want to open a .txt file in order to fill the table with the file's content. I've tried to replicate the code from an example of my teacher but i havent managed to "catch an exception" so far. This is my code:

```
buddyLoadFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(HauptFenster.this,
                                "Open File", FileDialog.LOAD);
                fd.setDirectory(".");
                fd.setVisible(true);
                try {
                    String filename = fd.getDirectory()
                            + fd.getFile();
                    buddyFileManager = new BuddyFileManager(filename);
                    buddyTableModel.setBuddies(buddyFileManager.load());
                    buddyTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            HauptFenster.this,
                            "error loading file", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            HauptFenster.this,
                            "invalid format of file.",
                            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
```

no matter what sort of files i opened, the programm succesfully fills the table with strings from the opened file. Is there any chance i will ever get an Exception with the code i am using?

This is my FileManager (in case it's neccesary):

```
public BuddyFileManager(String filename) {
        fileName = filename;
    }

    public List<Buddies> load() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        StreamTokenizer strTokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(br);
        strTokenizer.whitespaceChars(',', ',');
        List<Buddies> buddyListe = new ArrayList<Buddies>();

        while (strTokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            Buddies buddy = new Buddies();
            buddy.setName(strTokenizer.sval);
            strTokenizer.nextToken();
            buddy.setAlter(strTokenizer.nval);
            strTokenizer.nextToken();
            buddy.setLuegenindex(strTokenizer.nval);
            buddyListe.add(buddy);
        }
        br.close();
        return buddyListe;
    }
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your case you could get an IO Exception from the following, and more.

- The .txt file you were reading became unavailable.
- Some process closed the input stream which you were using with buffered reader to read data.
- If you try to read a .txt file which you don't have permission to.

etc. And also if you tried to read from an unsupported file format, you will get and exception. So for

> Is there any chance i will ever get an Exception with the code i am
>   using?

for this the answer is **yes**. It is possible to have an exception with the code you are using.If one of above things happened at the runtime, you will get an exception. And they will be handled by catch blocks.

This is not related to the question, but you'll might want to change your BuddyFileManager constructor code to avoid ambiguity.(in you case there is an ambiguity in variable filename)

```
public BuddyFileManager(String filename) {
        this.fileName = filename;
    }
```

this keyword resolves this ambiguity clearly by defining `this.filename` refers to the filename attribute in the BuddyFileManager class.

Comment: hello Nipun. thank you very much for your detailed answer and your advise regarding my BuddyFileManager constructor. good catch! highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to be a help :)